# Create string in same cell if partial match

Tags: excel, string-matching, partial

[image]

Column A: List of 8500 Parent SKU numbers
Column B: List of 8500 child SKU numbers

I need to run a formula that checks column B against column A for a partial match, and lists the cell data in column C,

There are several partial matches that need to be generated in column C, all seperated by a comma.

Comment: For the results you're showing, take `C2` for example.  You're looking for `GEN-ZUWI-FEM-5,` in column A.  However, you're returning matches from column B?  Do you mean that you want to look at `A2`, and return all matches in column B?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for the fast response. 
There are several versions or extensions of column A in column B, i want to pull them all into one cell in C seperated by a comma. Does that make sense? I'm a bit of a novice at this and usually use this site to find what i need to acheive but this one is a bit tricky to even explain :)

Comment: Do the child skus in column B really have a comma or comma & space suffix? Can it be removed?

Comment: I added the comma as a starting point but then hit a brick wall :) they can be removed if required but would need to be included in the results in column C

Comment: (Can you copy/paste the data here as a table? That way we don't have to recreate in Excel to work on it)

Comment: sorrty BRuce, trying to paste as table but cant work out how, will try the below now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do.  This UDF should do the trick with your data as-is.  Put this in a workbook module and you can call it (say you're in `C2`, with `=find_my_children(A2)`.  (You can name it whatever you want, I just had a bit of fun with it :P )

```
Function find_my_children(sku As String)
Dim parentRng As Range, childRng As Range
Dim results As String
results = ""

Set parentRng = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) ' Change these two as necessary
Set childRng = parentRng.Offset(0, 1)

Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In childRng
    If InStr(1, cel, sku) > 0 And InStr(1, results, cel) = 0 Then
        results = results & cel.Value
    End If
Next cel

If results = "" Then results = "NO DATA FOUND" ' You can comment this out, or change the message as needed.

find_my_children = results

End Function
```

[image]

<sub>(I assume you only have one worksheet. If you have multiple sheets, you'll want to qualify the ranges with that worksheet name. It's best practice though regardless of number of sheets, but for simplicity for OP I left that part out.)</sub>

Comment: hi Bruce, thanks for all your help. Is this the same as running a macro? AS I said Im a bit of a novice at this. I can get as far as pasting the code into a VBA but then cant seem to run it

Comment: You're a God among men Bruce, many thanks, got it to work :)) very happy

Comment: @RobertJohn if this answer is the one that solved your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking the check mark to the left. This lets other SO users know you no longer need assistance!

Comment: HI Bruce, hows tricks? I worked out how to add the module in Excel, project is coming together nicely. Quick questions, is there anyway to have this script omit the parent SKU from the the results?

Comment: @RobertJohn - Yeah, you should be able to do `=SUBSTITUTE(find_my_children(A2),$A2,""))`

Answer (score 1):

This seems right but is currently untested as I was not going to retype your data from an image.

```
Option Explicit

Sub collectChildSkus()
    Dim d As Long, dict As Object, skus As Variant

    Set dict = Create("scripting.dictionary")

    With Worksheets(1)
        With .Columns("B").Cells
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                           TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                           Comma:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 9))
        End With

        vals = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2

        For d = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            If dict.exists(vals(d, 1)) Then
                dict.Item(vals(d, 1)) = dict.Item(vals(d, 1)) & ", " & vals(d, 2)
            Else
                dict.Item(vals(d, 1)) = vals(d, 2)
            End If
        Next d

        .Cells(2, "C").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = dict.items
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: THank you Jeeped, the first solution worked for me, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Try a User-Defined Function. Basically it's a Concatenate If hybrid

```
Function FINDMATCHES(PARENT_RANGE As Range, CHILD_RANGE As Range)

Dim c As Range
Dim answer As String

    For Each c In CHILD_RANGE.Cells
        If c.Offset(, -1).Value = PARENT_RANGE.Value Then answer = answer & " " & c.Value
    Next c

    answer = Trim(answer)
    answer = Replace(answer, " ", ", ")

FINDMATCHES = answer

End Function
```

[image]